# C# Linq combine multiple values into data row

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

So im pulling down an xml string of records.  this one field is has a 1:M relationship.  Normally i load them like so:

`var entries = from x in xml.Descendants(Reporting)
select new {
additionalReportingValue = (string)x.Descendants("additionalReporting").FirstOrDefault()};`

but since additionalReportingValue can have multiple values for one record it fails.  I am unsure of how to loop through all the values and convert the many to 1.

here is an example of the feed and how it shows them, this record has 2 values(E, S):

```
<ns1:listOfAdditionalReportingValues>
<ns1:additionalReportingValue>E</ns1:additionalReportingValue> 
<ns1:additionalReportingValue>S</ns1:additionalReportingValue> 
</ns1:listOfAdditionalReportingValues>
```

any help would be appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine them into a single string, e.g. comma-delimited, you can use `Join` inline like this:

```
var entries = from x in xml.Descendants(Reporting)
    select new 
    {
        additionalReportingValue = string.Join
        (
            ",",
            x.Descendants("additionalReporting")
        )
    };
```

Comment: This is perfect.  I don't receive any errors now when running my exe.  But the values are coming in blank.  Curious why this is.....seems like what you posted would do the trick

Comment: You mean need to add Select, e.g. if you want to get each node's `Value` then use `x.Descendants("additionalReporting").Select( node => node.Value)`

Comment: added that to the line, and result holds the same.   testing with 100 records i know have values.  neither single or multiple valued ones are coming through.

Comment: Scratch what i last said.  your solution works perfectly.  I pulled the List values vs the Individual line and that was the trick.  Thanks man you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want.  I usually use an 'XDocument' and then continuing your 'descendants' method you have a collection to iterate over.  An example of your data(excluding the namespaces for ease of use) would be similar to:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        var data = "<listOfAdditionalReportingValues><additionalReportingValue>E</additionalReportingValue><additionalReportingValue>S</additionalReportingValue></listOfAdditionalReportingValues>";
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
        var rootDescendents = xdoc.Root.Descendants();
        var elementDescendents = xdoc.Element("listOfAdditionalReportingValues").Descendants();
        rootDescendents.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        rootDescendents.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));
        elementDescendents.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        elementDescendents.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Value));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```